# Reactjs Context returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

i need to make a global state for my application, i am trying to use react context, with class components, i have followed some videos but i cannot make it work as i need, i would like to know what i am doing wrong, and sorry if the question is not well structured, it is my first question.

My code:

**/Context.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const CartContext = React.createContext()

export class CartProvider extends Component{
state = {
    items:[],
    price:0
}    

render(){
    const {items,price} =this.state        
    return(
        <CartContext.Provider value={{items,price}}>
            {this.props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}
}

export default CartContext;
```

**/CartScreen.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Text} from "react-native";
import CartContext, {CartProvider} from "../context/Context";
class CartScreen extends Component {   
static contextType = CartContext
      render() {
        console.log("Context:")
        console.log(this.context)
        return (
            <CartProvider>
                <Text>CartScreen</Text>
            </CartProvider>
        );
    }
}   
export default CartScreen;
```

And this get from the console:

> Context: undefined

however if I modify the default parameter when creating the context, the console returns the parameter

```
const CartContext = React.createContext("test")
```

Console returns:

> Context: test

It's as if I'm always taking the default parameter no matter what I'm assigning to the value of the provider.

Comment: I have not use class base components or react native, but I think you need to destructure your context in your the render function  const { items,price } = useContext(CartContext);

Answer (score 0):

You have access to `CartContext` values from the components you pass to it as `props.children`.

So if you need access to context values inside `CartScreen`, you have to wrap it inside `CartProvider`.

```
return (<CartProvider>
          <CartScreen/>
        </CartProvider>)
```

And inside `CartScreen` you don't need to use `CartProvider` anymore:

```
class CartScreen extends Component {   
static contextType = CartContext
  render() {
    console.log("Context:")
    console.log(this.context)
    return (
             <Text>CartScreen</Text>
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: i cant wrap the cart component in App.js, because im using createAppContainer with a switch navigator inside, is there any way to implement it or should I change the code of my App.js